# how to update one field using formGroup in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, rest, formgroups

I want to update one field in form, I have used this code but it doesn't work, I have got this error : PATCH http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/update/16 422 (Unprocessable Content)

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.appointmentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id_t: ['', Validators.required],
    });

    if (this.editData) {
      this.appointmentForm.controls['id_t'].setValue(this.editData.id_t);
    }
  }

  update() {
    this.api.putAppointment(this.appointmentForm.value, this.editData.id)
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          alert('Update Successfuly');
          this.appointmentForm.reset();
          this.dialogRef.close('update');
        },
        error: () => {
          alert('Error while updating the record');
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Can you please share `api` service `putAppointment` method code ?

Comment: public function update(Request $request, Appointment $appointment)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'id_t' => 'required|max:100|unique:appointments', ]);

Comment: $appointment->update([
            "id_t" => $request->id_t,
        ]);
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Appoinment updated successfully',
            'service' => $appointment
        ], 201);
    }

Comment: This my function in laravel

Comment: Do you really intend to pass `this.appointmentForm.value` to your API, or you are meant to pass `this.appointmentForm.value.id_t`?  And where in your code value of `this.editData` is getting set?

Comment: I want to pass this.appointmentForm.value.id_t . for editData is a variable in constrator 
     constructor(private formBuilder : FormBuilder, 
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public editData : any,
    private api :AppointmentService, 
    private dialogRef : MatDialogRef<AppointmentDialogComponent>) { }

Answer (score 0):

```
 updateAppointment(){      
       console.log(this.editData.id) 
       console.log(this.appointmentForm.get('id_t')?.value)
       
  this.api.putAppointment(this.editData.id,
    {"id_t" : this.appointmentForm.get('id_t')?.value})
    .subscribe({
       next:(res)=>{            
         alert("Technicien updated Successfuly");                   
         this.appointmentForm.reset();
         this.dialogRef.close('update');  
  },
  error:()=>{
    alert("Error while updating the record");
  }                      
})
```

Comment: In the api function the data to update is json formt, so I add { "id_t"  : this.appointmentForm.get('id_t')?.value} and it work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).